# Decorate/override default MethodArgumentResolvers in Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'd like to put some predefined data to the mvc model.

I created custom annotation, and custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. 
My Controller now looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}")
public void findById(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id, @CustomAnnotation Model model) {}
```

But Spring mvc has about 30 predefined MethodArgumentResolvers for different annotations and classes, and for Model.class Spring uses ModelMethodProcessor.

Can I somehow override it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I extend RequestMappingHandlerAdapter and overrided

```
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
    List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers = new ArrayList<>();
    argumentResolvers.add(new AveModelMethodProcessor());
    argumentResolvers.addAll(this.getArgumentResolvers());
    this.setArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
}
```

After that I replaced original RequestMappingHandlerAdapter with custom one:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration {

   @Override
   protected RequestMappingHandlerAdapter createRequestMappingHandlerAdapter(){
        return new MyRequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
   }

}
```

Now it works. Is it optimal way?